# How to split strings with two chars ('||')

Tags: c#, split

```
otherMatchArray= "March | Monday | Tuesday|| December | Wednesday | Friday"


string[] matchData = otherMatchArray.Split('||');
```

How can I split one string and then split it again using || and | ?

Comment: Yes, it's here https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string[] matchData = otherMatchArray.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```